# getting Ansible bad python interpreter error?

Tags: python, ansible

I installed ansible on MAC High Sierra 10.13.3 and when I am trying to run

"ansible --version" I am receiving following error

-bash: /usr/local/bin/ansible: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Please let me know if you have ran into same issue or have solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/usr/local/bin/ansible` has PATH `"/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7"` on the first line. and in `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/` directory I had python3.6 instead of python2.7.

So I changed PATH on file `vi /usr/local/bin/ansible`

from `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7`
to `#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.6`
and that fixed the issue

Verification :

```sh
$ ansible --version
  ansible 2.5.0
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/Users/<username>/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/<username>/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.4 (default, Mar  1 2018, 18:36:50) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]


$ ansible localhost -m ping

  localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
  }


$ ansible localhost -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_distribution' 
  localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution": "MacOSX"
    },
    "changed": false
  }
```

Comment: Python 3 support is still in a tech preview status, so you'd better just install python2.7 into your system and not edit source files.

Comment: Took me a bit to puzzle this out, but I had to add Python to my path on an Macbook M1.  `export PATH="/Users/hss151/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH"` This was a bit unexpected. (Be sure you restart your terminal session in your IDE or source your .zprofile file.)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I am using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage my python versions and $PATH and symlinks were all correct pointing to the correct paths.

#### Check your python paths

```sh
$ pyenv which python
  /Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/python
$ which python
  /Users/<username>/.pyenv/shims/python
```

#### Check ansible configuration

ansible configuration at `/usr/local/bin/ansible` pointed the correct python version 3.7

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
.
.
.
```

but `ansible --version` returned python 2.7 as its interpreter

```sh
$ ansible --version
  ansible 2.9.12
  configured module search path = ['/Users/<username>/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/2.7.16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/2.7.16/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.16 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:02:51) [Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)]
```

#### Ansible for Python3

[Official ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html) said to use pip3 to install ansible for python3 and I uninstalled ansible and reinstalled using pip3 but the interperter still pointed to python2.7.

Finally I manually added [.ansible.cfg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings) file in my home path and configured python interpreted manually by adding

```
  ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python
```

[Example config file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg) for ansible.cfg

Now ansible is configured for python3 correctly

```
ansible 2.9.12
  config file = /Users/<username>/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/<username>/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.3 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:02:51) [Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the python version might be pushing into some compatibility issues

It happens, when we have multiple python versions installed in our OS.

Simple steps for troubleshooting:

1. Check the python version
   command: `which python /usr/bin/python`
2. Create a soft link to the path
   command : `ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7`

I hope it will fix the error.